# Django: Testing app causes Tastypie error

Tags: python, django, testing, tastypie, django-south

I am trying to test my Django app via

```
python manage.py test project
```

but I get the error message that

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "tastypie_apiaccess" already exists
```

How is that possible? Never tested before. Is that in relation to the migration files I have stored in the app folder and `test` uses the migrations to create the sqlite copy of my db?

I am running `South` as a migration app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be related to south migrations. If so, you can avoid this by using `SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False`, then test runner will use syncdb instead of migrate.